# JQuery : remove current div in image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image slider to change between images, With two buttons, the first adds an item to the slider, the second removes the current image from the slider but does not work.

How can I make the remove item button remove the current item from the slider?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

$('#NewsItem').click(function () {
    
    var maindiv = $("<div class='mySlides fade'>")
                 .append($("<div class='numbertext'>4 / 4</div>"))
                 .append($("<img src='4.jpg' style='width:100%;height:650px' />"))
                 .append($("<div class='text'>Caption Four</div>"));

    $('.slideshow-container').append(maindiv);
    $('.footer').append($("<span class='dot' onclick='currentSlide(4)'></span>"));
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

 <button id="NewsItem">Add Item</button> 
    <button id="RemoveItem">remove Item</button> 

 <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="2.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="3.jpg" style="width:100%" /> 
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
     
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div style="text-align:center" class="footer">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
```

Comment: where's your `$('#RemoveItem').click(function ()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code to remove active slide. But this may cause errors when your list get exhausted as method you have used for sliding is not proper. You need to track current slide by setting index as `data-attr` and retrive index on button click.ie index of slide should created for dynamic slides also which may be auto incremented.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    slides[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    slides[slideIndex - 1].id=slideIndex;
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
$('#RemoveItem').click(function () {
 $(".active").remove();
});
$('#NewsItem').click(function () {
    
    var maindiv = $("<div class='mySlides fade'>")
                 .append($("<div class='numbertext'>4 / 4</div>"))
                 .append($("<img src='4.jpg' style='width:100%;height:650px' />"))
                 .append($("<div class='text'>Caption Four</div>"));

    $('.slideshow-container').append(maindiv);
    $('.footer').append($("<span class='dot' onclick='currentSlide(4)'></span>"));
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.slideshow-container{
 margin-top:20px;
} 
/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

 <button id="NewsItem">Add Item</button> 
    <button id="RemoveItem">remove Item</button> 

 <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="2.jpg" style="width:100%" />
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="3.jpg" style="width:100%" /> 
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
     
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div style="text-align:center" class="footer">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
```